# Как полностью закрыть sql соединение и очистить данные?

Tags: c#, sql, mono

Делаю запрос к базе. При следующем запросе у меня меняется `offset`. Откуда то берутся данные, которых в этом запросе и в помине нет. Они были в предыдущем запросе. Поэтому думаю что не до конца или закрыл соединение, или очистил данные

```
 public string returnData(int offset, string razdel)
    {
        List<RecyclerViewNews> list = new List<RecyclerViewNews>();

        using (dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbcon.Open();
            using (IDbCommand cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT n.id, n.title, n.full_image, n.date, n.preview_text, n.url FROM news n JOIN news_type on n.id_news=news_type.id WHERE news_type.name LIKE '%{0}%'  ORDER BY n.date desc Limit {1} offset {2}", razdel,10, offset*10);
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        RecyclerViewNews news = new RecyclerViewNews();
                        news.Id = (int) reader["id"];
                        news.Title = (string)reader["title"];
                        news.FullImage = (string)reader["full_image"];
                        news.PreviewText = (string)reader["preview_text"];
                        news.Date = (string)reader["date"];
                        news.Url = (string) reader["url"];
                        list.Add(news);
                    }

                }

            }
            dbcon.Close();
        }
        var m = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: а где сам `offset` обявлен? это статическое поле?

Comment: пардон. Забыл вставить. offset всегда равен 10

Comment: ну раз `offset` всегда равен 10 - то ваш запрос всегда выдает строки с 11 по 20. В чем суть вопроса?

Comment: тьфу ты)) он у меня равен offset = offset * 10.

Comment: т.е в первом запросе будет limit 10 offset 0. Во втором limit 10 offset 10; В третьем limit 10 offset 20;

Comment: ок. тогда тот же вопрос - а как переменная (или поле) offset объявлено - то, которое вы на 10 умножаете?

Comment: public string returnData(int offset, string razdel) вот на вход оно идет.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25622/discussion-between-radzhab-654654-and-pashapash).

Comment: ну значит смотрите в отладчике "плохую" команду, которая выдает "неправильные" данные. попробуйте ее напрямую на базе выполнить. никаких "очисток данных" и "окончательных закрытий" нет. выдает всегда именно то, что выбрал конкретный SQL запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Передвижение ссылки. 
Следует добавить объект *RecyclerViewNews news = new RecyclerViewNews();* раньше цикла.
Инитить в цикле 
*news = new RecyclerViewNews();*
И далее всё как написано.